# How to install Ubuntu on windows tablet?

Tags: tablet

I have a tablet bangho aero jo810 with win 10 32 bits, I want to install ubuntu.  How do I do it?!

Comment: Are you sure the hardware is compatible?

Comment: The hardware unfortunately isn't Linux friendly, at all. It uses an Intel Bay Trail Z3735F which is known for making it almost impossible to have a decent Ubuntu experience in it. Expect WIFi, audio and likely the touchscreen NOT to work and also constant and unexpected freezes.

Comment: And there's more: You would need to prepare a special USB installer due to the 64-bit CPU combined with a 32-bit UEFI. That's the reason why it comes with a 32-bit Windows but you can't use 32-bit Ubuntu with that (no UEFI support) and the 64-bit Ubuntu doesn't boot in 32-bit UEFI. In summary, you would need to be an expert to install it and even experts can't solve most of the issues I mentioned in the previous comment after installing.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, then could you put a windows 7?  is that the Windows that is installed VA Very slow